# Error Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am developing an application with xamarin.Forms, it happens that when testing the application in iOS it works fine in the emulator but this error appears on the physical device. Anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

[image: As you can see]

Comment: Seems that you added a manual assembly reference to a Xamarin.Android based assembly.